# How to write custom data into signature field of an EXE after signing?

Tags: c#, .net-core, digital-signature, code-signing, authenticode

I've an EXE which is code signed and saved on the server. When any user wants to download the EXE, I've to embed a user specific information into the EXE which I get to know when the download request comes from the user.

Constraints:

1. I can't rebuild EXE.
2. I can't resign EXE.
3. Whatever I do, I have to make sure the integrity of content and signature remains intact.

I came to know that it is possible to store custom data in the signature field from this [blog](https://vcsjones.dev/authenticode-stuffing-tricks/) post signing. This blog mentioned three ways:

1. Padding/stuffing
2. Unauthenticated attributes of signature
3. Additional certificate field of signature

The first technique mentioned over there is padding. In this technique we can leverage the unsed bytes in the last 8 bytes of the signature as signature always takes up space which is in multiles of 8.

So let's say if signature is of 60 bytes then 64 bytes will be allocated which is the nearest multiple of 8. Signature will use 60 bytes and we can use remaining 4 bytes to stuff our custom data.

I observed a couple of signed EXEs saw that we can indeed get 1 to 7 bytes:

1. git-bash.exe   - 2 byte
2. cmtrace.exe    - 3 bytes
3. chrome.exe     - 0 bytes
4. iisexpress.exe - 0 bytes
5. iexplore.exe   - 2 bytes

But as you can see above in some cases it can be zero as well. The C# .NET Core code below tells me the starting position of signature and length of signature in any EXE:

```
public static byte[] ExtractPadding(string filePath, out long signatureStartLocation, out int signatureLengthInUse)
{
    signatureLengthInUse = 0;
    using (var file = new PortableExecutable(filePath))
    {
        var dosHeader = file.GetDosHeader();
        var peHeader = file.GetPEHeader(dosHeader);
        var signatureLocation = peHeader.DataDirectories[ImageDataDirectoryEntry.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY];
        signatureStartLocation = signatureLocation.VirtualAddress;
        using (var signatureData = file.ReadDataDirectory(signatureLocation))
        {
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(signatureData))
            {
                var winCertLength = reader.ReadUInt32();
                var winCertRevision = reader.ReadUInt16();
                var winCertType = reader.ReadUInt16();
                if (winCertRevision != 0x200 && winCertRevision != 0x100)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                if (winCertType != 0x0002)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int read;
                    Span<byte> buffer = stackalloc byte[0x400];
                    while ((read = reader.Read(buffer)) > 0)
                    {
                        memoryStream.Write(buffer.Slice(0, read));
                    }
                    var winCertificate = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    var signer = new SignedCms();
                    signer.Decode(winCertificate);
                    var roundTrip = signer.Encode();
                    var sizeDifference = winCertificate.Length - roundTrip.Length;
                    var difference = new byte[sizeDifference];
                    signatureLengthInUse = roundTrip.Length;
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(winCertificate, roundTrip.Length, difference, 0, difference.Length);
                    return difference;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For my use case 7 bytes of space is very limiting as I need to pass data little more than that. Can someone help me in this if there is any other way or extension of the current approach which can help me write more data in signature field without invalidating the EXE or signature?

Comment: There is nothing "secret" about a key just because you stuff it into some little-known location of the file -- the key is still accessible to anyone who has the file and knows where you're storing it. As the key bytes would not be part of the signature, they wouldn't be verified either. It would be a simple matter for someone to get two accounts, compare the files and find the "secret" location. Combined with the limited size (or none, in some cases) this method doesn't seem viable. A separate file that you encrypt and sign, with a periodic online verification, would be simpler.

Comment: In the use case I've, there is no other option. Earlier we were sending that user specific code to users in email and then asking to punch in when prompted by EXE. That was very error prone when the code was very long. Our users are completely new to computer so they can't do Ctrl + C and then Ctrl + V for long code. So we thought we would send that user code along with the EXE itself to avoid user errors. I've removed the word 'secret' from my post to avoid distraction from core agenda.

Comment: My idea would be to wrap your payload executable in a self-extracting archive, so you can include whatever and even help the user along in getting things to activate. This archive/helper EXE could then be what's generated on the fly, instead of trying to modify the original without breaking things.

Comment: Why does it have to be in the signature field? Can't you just link in a blank resource - an appropriately sized array of zeroes, say - and then patch that?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That would invalidate the signature AFAIK.

Comment: @IanKemp: Ah, right, undoubtedly it would.

Answer (score 0):

Say you find a piece of the file that can contain some random bytes and isn't affected by the signature, and you stuff your unique identifier in there... what's to stop any end-user from doing the exact same thing, essentially defeating your copy-protection? That's the whole point of code signing - *to stop people from messing with a file in this exact manner*.

If you "can't" (which I suspect is more like "don't want to") re-build and re-sign the file for each unique user, you can't embed your unique identifier into it. The fact that an arbitrary blog post from *half a decade ago* notes this technique doesn't mean that it works today, or that it will continue to work in the future, or that Microsoft won't flag your EXE as malicious. If you want to colour outside the lines, be prepared to be burned.

Comment: My primary goal is _not_ copy-protection. I've to send some data which will be used by the EXE at client side. That data is user-specific which I get to know _only_ when user wants to download that EXE. Signature is the most apt area where I can write this user data else the signature will become invalid. And then, Windows will start giving security prompts when user tries to run the downloaded EXE.